# how do i consume or map same ports on two docker containers

Tags: docker

I am running one application in docker_container_1 with several ports being mapped with local.

Thereby, I can access the service from docker_container_1 on the local machine.

Now, I want to access the service from docker_container_1 to another docker_container (docker_container_2), but I couldn't create a docker_container_2 because I can't map the port that is mapped to docker_container_1.

How can I access a service from docker_1 bind to port (say 5555) to another docker_2.

Answer (score 0):

So, Initially I have two docker images:

```
    REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
bert_client_api      latest              2fa40dd05152        17 hours ago        841MB
bert_services        latest              1695c35fde34        18 hours ago        2.74GB
```

and I made a container for `bert-services` image, with few ports mapped.

```
$ sudo docker run -it -v /home/jugs/Desktop/BERT-Pretrained/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1/:/model/ -p 5000:5000 -p 127.0.0.1:5555:5555 -p 127.0.0.1:5556:5556 bert_services /bin/bash
```

so I have the running container as:

```
(myenv) jugs@jugs:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
de9bb74a0e04        bert_client_api     "/bin/bash"         9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                                                     suspicious_lewin
```

[I ran the hosting service from the container: `de9bb74a0e04` ]

Now, if i want all the service from the host-machine (including the container service), the way is to use `--net=host`, with

```
$ sudo docker run -it  -v /home/jugs/Desktop/geeksforgeeks/dockerBertClient/:/mydir/ --net=host bert_client_api /bin/bash
```

Now, u have two containers that can communicate easily.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
de9bb74a0e04        bert_client_api     "/bin/bash"         9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                                                     suspicious_lewin
f9d5a35a75bb        bert_services       "/bin/bash"         18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:5555-5556->5555-5556/tcp   quizzical_minsky
```